# Is it possible to detect if shiftwidth/tabstop/etc was set in modeline

Tags: vimscript

I have my own detection of the file indent settings based on the file contents. All good and works ok for my needs but...

When I open a `c` source file of the vim itself it overrides options set by `modeline`:

```
/* vi:set ts=8 sts=4 sw=4 noet:
 *
 * VIM - Vi IMproved›   by Bram Moolenaar
 *
 * Do ":help uganda"  in Vim to read copying and usage conditions.
 * Do ":help credits" in Vim to see a list of people who contributed.
 * See README.txt for an overview of the Vim source code.
 */
```

I would like not to set indent options based on the file contents(in my func) if file has corresponding `modeline` options set.

So is there a way I can detect it in vimscript?

Comment: Hmmm, I can probably detect modeline myself in the same function...

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I don't want to turn off the modeline -- I would like to conform to the settings provided there (PRs for vim)

Comment: ohhh I see—you want the modeline to take precedence. Hm. Perhaps some result of `execute('verbose setlocal xxx?')` can be parsed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your locale is English-like, the following should work:

```
:echo (execute('verbose setlocal ts?')->split('\n')[-1] =~# 'Last set from modeline line \d\+')
        \ ? 'set from modeline' 
        \ : 'set elsewhere'
```

Not sure about handling different locales. For example, my system has `LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8`, so the message appears differently:

```
    Modifié la dernière fois dans ligne de mode ligne 41
```

And the obvious function wrapper:

```
function IsSetFromModeline(opts) abort
  return mapnew(a:opts, {_, v -> execute(printf('verbose setlocal %s?', v))->split('\n')[-1] =~# 'Last set from modeline line \d\+'})
endfunction

echo IsSetFromModeline(['tabstop', 'shiftwidth'])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can install an [OptionSet](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#OptionSet) autocommand. If an option was triggered by a modeline, it will be in the special v variable: `v:option_type`. Note: there are a whole bunch of `v:option...` variables for all different kinds.

You could simply test the autocommand using the following example:

```
au OptionSet * echomsg printf("OptionSet: %s: option: %s old: %s new: %s, type: %s", strftime('%T'), expand("<amatch>"), v:option_old, v:option_new, v:option_command)
```

Another work-around would be to simply make Vim reprocess the `BufReadPost` autocommands, which should re-evaluate the modeline:

`doauto BufReadPost <filename>`

Not sure what would work better for your use-case.